# Adding data to database from frontend to backend

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm getting this error code: "unclosed quotation mark after the character string" on the line: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

I've looked, but I don't know what's wrong. I also tried just putting two of the textboxe, but I can't seem to debug it.  Please advise. Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
namespace Inventory
{
    public partial class NewData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=ActioNet1234");


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }//end page load

        protected void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory values('" + Typetb.Text + " ',' " + Maketb.Text + "','" + Modeltb.Text + "','" + Serialtb.Text + "','" + Assignedtb.Text + "','" + Locationtb.Text + "','" + Notestb.Text + "')'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            status.Visible = true;
            status.Text = "Added succesffully!";


            Typetb.Text = "";
            Maketb.Text = "";
            Modeltb.Text = "";
            Serialtb.Text = "";
            Assignedtb.Text = "";
            Locationtb.Text = "";
            Notestb.Text = "";

        }//end add button

        protected void clearButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Typetb.Text = "";
            Maketb.Text = "";
            Modeltb.Text = "";
            Serialtb.Text = "";
            Assignedtb.Text = "";
            Locationtb.Text = "";
            Notestb.Text = "";


        }//clear button




    }//end 
}//end
```

Comment: Use Parameters or fall prey to [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have unnecessary single quote at the end of your query.

```
Notestb.Text + "')'
                  ^^ here
```

#### But more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
   // Set your CommandText property with your parameter definitions
   // Add your parameters and their values with Add method
   // Open your connection
   // Execute your query.
}
```

Comment: damn. i'm an idiot. I hate when it's this easy and I can't figure it out lol Thanks so much!

Comment: @TerrenceSanchez Glad to help.

Comment: like this?  

using(var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.10.101.188;Initial Catalog=ActioNetITInventory;User ID=rails.sa;Password=ActioNet1234"))

Comment: using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {

 cn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory values (' "+Typetb.text+" ' )";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", Typetb);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

cn.Close();

Comment: @No, define your `CommandText` as `INSERT INTO Inventory values(@type)` and than add this parameter as `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", Typetb);`.

Comment: last question: how do I execute the query? I tried 

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

and i'm getting the error message: "No mapping exist from object type"

Comment: and I tried:  `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader():` and it also gives me the same error message

Comment: @TerrenceSanchez What is the error message exactly? Can you please update your question with the code you tried?

Comment: the code is the same thing, but when I use `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader` or `cmd.ExecutreNonQuery()` the get the error message saying _No mapping exist from object type_

Answer (score 0):

Your command ends with an extra single quote. It should be:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory values('" + 
    Typetb.Text + " ',' " + Maketb.Text + "','" + Modeltb.Text + 
    "','" + Serialtb.Text + "','" + Assignedtb.Text + "','" +
    Locationtb.Text + "','" + Notestb.Text + "')";
```

Comment: No problem. Also I would definitely use @Soner 's advice on parameterized queries and the use of `using`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory values('" + Typetb.Text + " ',' " 
    + Maketb.Text + "','" + Modeltb.Text + "','" + Serialtb.Text + "','" + 
    Assignedtb.Text + "','" + Locationtb.Text + "','" + Notestb.Text + "')'";
```

there you single comma ' after the right bracket ).
Should have been:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory values('" + Typetb.Text + " ',' " 
    + Maketb.Text + "','" + Modeltb.Text + "','" + Serialtb.Text + "','" 
    + Assignedtb.Text + "','" + Locationtb.Text + "','" + Notestb.Text 
    + "')";
```